# Setting & finding a svn repository on a system in LAN

Tags: windows, eclipse, svn, repository

I have installed TortoiseSVN on machine 192.168.1.56, & want to synchronise with it from 192.168.1.60, when i insert the repository address in URL like this "file:///192.168.1.56/D:/Repository" and click finish, i get the message "Location information has been specified incorrectly" what is the proper format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually TortoiseSVN recommends not to do that as you can read [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup.html):

> If you were thinking about setting up a multi-user repository on a network share, think again. Read the section called "[Accessing a Repository on a Network Share](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share)” to find out why we think this is a bad idea. Setting up a server is not as hard as it sounds, and will give you better reliability and probably speed too.

I recommend you to set-up [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html) and you can check how to do it in [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html) TortoiseSVN step-by-step tutorial to achieve it. Otherwise you will need to install and set-up WebDAV (e.g. `libapache2-svn`) in a capable web server (e.g. `apache2`).

Answer (score 5):

It is able to do that on LAN.
1. Remember to share the folder you use as repository
2. On pc B, select SVN checkout..., click the browse button, locate to that shared folder, like this:
[image]
And it's done.

Comment: Thanks for your 1st point, i was missing that. Than i used file://ip-address/repository shared folder

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) or a [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) server? For the svn client TortoiseSVN you need a server. In your case I would recommend to use a svn server with a graphical user interface for Windows: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

A valid URL may look like this `svn://192.168.1.56/repository`. The repository has to be created on the server.

Comment: Hi there, cant that machine be any system on the LAN, instead of being server.

Comment: Yes, of course. "Server" means "server software", which you can install anywhere where it is accessable from your client, also on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try

> file://192.168.1.56/Repository

I am not installing the server because I didn't want my computer resources to be used by the server (as I will be using this computer as a desktop as well) ,Also we are sharing among 2 members only so it worked for me in-spite of some disadvantages.